# submitting a form using jquery on jquery ui dialog close function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have a button on my jquery ui dialog like this:

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Multiple Account Login" style="display: none;">
     <a class="close-btn" href="#" id="A16">
                <img src="../../Content/NewDesign/images/cross.png" width="28" height="28" alt="close dialog" onclick="closeMultipleAccountDialog();" /></a>
            <div class="clear-n">
            </div>
</div>
```

This buttons when clicked calls a function

```
    function closeMultipleAccountDialog() {
        $("#hdfAccount").val("cancel");
        $("#hdPage").val("151API");
        $("#hdID").val($("#ID").val());
        $("#hdPSSWD").val($("#PSSWD").val());
        $("#hdACCID").val($("#ACCID").val());
        $("#hdPASSWDINT").val($("#PASSWDINT").val());
        $("#frmsetAccount").submit();
        $(this).dialog("close");        
     }
```

This function need to submit  a form :

```
      <form action="../Account/SetAccount" method="post" id="frmsetAccount">
                            <div class="flds-up">
                                <div class="lft-txt">
                                    Account <span>:</span></div>
                                <div class="user-fld">
                                    <%=  ViewData["MyAccountsList"] %>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clear-n">
                                </div>
                                <input type="hidden" id="hdfAccount" name="hdfAccount" value="" />
                                <input type="hidden" id="hdPage" name="hdPage" value="" />
                                <input type="hidden" id="hdID" name="hdID" value="" />
                                <input type="hidden" id="hdPSSWD" name="hdPSSWD" value="" />
                                <input type="hidden" id="hdACCID" name="hdACCID" value="" />
                                <input type="hidden" id="hdPASSWDINT" name="hdPASSWDINT" value="" />
                            </form>

and dialog code is like this:

$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                resizable: true,
                modal: true,
                width: 458,
                Height: 184,

                buttons: {
                    "Login": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        $("#hdfAccount").val("login");
                        $("#hdPage").val("151API");
                        $("#hdPage").val("151API");
                        $("#hdID").val($("#ID").val());
                        $("#hdPSSWD").val($("#PSSWD").val());
                        $("#hdACCID").val($("#ACCID").val());
                        $("#hdPASSWDINT").val($("#PASSWDINT").val());
                        $("#frmsetAccount").submit();
                    }                   
                },
                open: function (event) {
                    $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find('button:contains("Login")').focus();
                    $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find('button:contains("Login")').addClass('customokbutton');
                },
                close: function (event) {
                    closeMultipleAccountDialog();
                }
            });
```

It works on login button and form is submitted but not on Dialog close. Please suggest me a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

it wont work because of the `event.preventDefault()` in jquery ui code:

```
        uiDialogTitlebarClose = $( "<a href='#'></a>" )
            .addClass( "ui-dialog-titlebar-close  ui-corner-all" )
            .attr( "role", "button" )
            .click(function( event ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                that.close( event );
            })
```

when using dialog("close"). it will close the dialog and prevent all other functions associated with the click event. you can remove it and your code will work, but will also activate the link `<a class="close-btn" href="#" id="A16">` that was prevented before!